# Getting details of charges for international payments

Tags: international-transfer, swift

I'm trying to understand how costs are calculated when making an international payment via SWIFT, as the whole system seems rather opaque.

If I understand correctly, an international payment might go directly from the sending to the receiving bank, or might involve one or more "correspondent" banks along the way. All of these banks can choose to levy a charge.

Is there any standard way to find out what the charges will be in advance of making a payment? In most cases banks just say things like "We have no control over the fees", e.g. [here](http://www.nationwide.co.uk/support/payments-and-transfers/specialist-payments/swift-payments#xtab:fees-and-charges) and [here (page 8)](https://www.credit-suisse.com/media/assets/private-banking/docs/ch/privatkunden/konditionenuebersicht-1501874-en.pdf).

In the particular example I have in mind, I've tried asking the sending bank (of which I'm a customer) and they've claimed they don't know.

If I can't find out before making the payment, is there any way to find out afterwards? i.e. if I send `X`, and `(X-K)` arrives, can I find out who charged the `K`, and perhaps get a proper receipt/invoice for it?

Comment: What is the objective. This is routinely done for corporate clients.

Comment: @Dheer for example to decide which of multiple possible recipient banks to use, or to figure out alternate arrangements if the price is too high.

Comment: The costs are like this:  first you pay a lot.  Then you pay a lot to someone else. After that, you pay a lot to someone else.  Finally, when you get the funds, a large amount if subtracted and that's paid to someone.  Then you pay a fee, which is taken from the gross. Finally, you pay a number of fees taken from the net.  **Honestly, it is such a rip off you just have to not worry about it.**  It's the biggest scam out there.  You will never, ever, ever get a clear accounting of what you paid  :/

Comment: Use transferwise instead...?

Comment: @ollie299792458 not currently an option in my situation

Comment: @ollie299792458 my situation has nothing to do with INR. The main issue I have is with the sending bank, but the details are irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam transferwise accepts deposits via debit card? If your bank doesn't like it, just open a new account in the sending currency and transfer the money across.  If you're not planning on making a payment and this is just an interesting intellectual exercise, ignore me.

Comment: @ollie299792458 it's a restricted account that doesn't let me do very much. If Transferwise (or anyone else like Revolut) introduces personal IBANs in CHF associated directly with my name, like they have for EUR, it would also solve my actual problem. But I think the core question is more general than that and useful anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> If I understand correctly, an international payment might go directly from the sending to the receiving bank, or might involve one or more "correspondent" banks along the way. All of these banks can choose to levy a charge.

Yes this is right. For a given currency pair, country, the chain of banks is known. More often on websites. For Example if I need to send money from India to UK, If I choose Citi in India, I know Citi's Correspondant is for UK. etc.

> Is there any standard way to find out what the charges will be in advance of making a payment?

Only on standard remittance corridors, the price are upfront advised. On a normal SWIFT, few Banks do offer garunteed payment and advise the total fee. However this is slightly more that normal route.

> if I send X, and (X-K) arrives, can I find out who charged the K,

Depending on currency pair, you can see who the correspondants are and indirectly find out. Most banks charge similar fee.

Corporate customer do negotiate the fees with some of the correspondant banks.

Comment: So how do I find this information for a given currency and pair of banks?

Comment: Individual Bank's Website. SWIFT provides paid service to members.

Comment: Most/all banks I've looked at don't have this information on their websites.

Comment: Is this UK we are talking about? Because most Indian Banks have it up on the website.

Comment: The UK and Switzerland are what I'm currently interested in, but it's a general question.

Comment: "So how do I find this information for a given currency and pair of banks"   **it's utterly impossible.**  Just forget it.  It's just one of those things about life.

Comment: This seems difficult for Europe Banks. There is a list for making payments from Switzerland to UK but can't find something other way round. http://www.rbsinternational.com/content/corporate/international/downloads/RBSI_Correspondent_Banks.pdf and http://www.lloydsbank.com.hk/pdf/ims/How_to_Make_a_Payment.pdf